# how to : multiline to oneline by removing newlines

Tags: python, newline, multiline

I'm a newbie in python who is starting to learn it.

I wanted to make a script that count the same letter pattern in a text file. Problem is my text file has multiple lines. I couldn't find some of my patterns as they went over to the next line.

My file and the pattern are a DNA sequence.

Example:

```
'attctcgatcagtctctctagtgtgtgagagactctagctagatcgtccactcactgac**ga 
tc**agtcagt**gatc**tctcctactacaaggtgacatgagtgtaaattagtgtgagtgagtgaa'
```

I'm looking for `'gatc'`. The second one was counted, but the first wasn't.

So, how can I make this file to a one line text file?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the lines when you read the pattern from the file:

```
    fd = open('dna.txt', 'r')
    dnatext = ''.join(fd.readlines())
    dnatext.count('gatc')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dnatext = text.replace('\n', '')    // join text lines
gatc_count = dnatext.count('gatc')  // count 'gatc' occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
dnatext = "".join(dnatext.split("\n"))
```